# Code comparison when asking

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking-questions, code

What if `<Code Sample>`s and formatted code will compare with existing questions' `<Code Sample>`s and formatted code and let the user (who asks) to know if there are similar question?

For example, I'll put some code in my question. Then it will be compared. Then there will be a list of "most similar questions (with most similar code)":

```
Qestion 1              > 99% similarity Old_Qestion 1
                       > 76% similarity Old_Qestion 2
                       > and so on.
```

I think this will reduce the number of similar questions (if SO need as more as possible various questions because all of them are unique so any user will find exactly what he\she needs).

**PS** This feature doesn't pretend to be realised (or being put under consideration) at the nearest time. But when technologies will become better, when there will become very good algorhytms for analysing `<Code examples>`... That's what I mean. It's not really required but recommendable/advisable.

**PSS** When you ask a question there is a list of similar questions under *Title* field. But I don't know what algorhytm it uses. (Suppose, by checking the questions with similar **Titles**, but not code ---> **when I write there `code` only, it doesn't show me similar questions!**)

Comment: Please, comment your downvotes.

Comment: Potential here for a mismatch is when people have typos...

Comment: I mean, the number of specific functions etc. I know that there are *UDFs* (User defined functions). And questions that comtain these functions are unique. But there are so simple (users don't understand what they are asking): this is questions about exercises in books and tutorials... They dodn't contain UDFs (as a rule) and they are often being marked as **off-topic (requires a minimal understanding of the question)**.

Comment: I don't think this is going to yield very accurate results. Besides, who checks the similar question suggestions anyway?

Comment: I doubt the results from this would outweigh the required work to implement such a thing.

Comment: So, you're suggesting that code within existing questions be compared to code being written in a new question as part of the "questions with existing answers" feature?

Comment: @JonW, This will help the users (who asks questions) to see the list of similar question and read them. If there is nothing that wil help his/her he will ask his/her own question.

Comment: @JulianKhlevnoy: Doesn't StackOverflow already show a list of similar questions when you're posting something?

Comment: @JonW, only by *Title*, not by the question's content. (`code examples`)

Comment: One problem I see with this proposal is that different people (or even the same person) can have *very* different questions about the exact same block of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything that's a good idea and improvement is great, but you haven't stated how this will work.

Looking at one language (PHP say), a lot of the PHP code around SO has a lot of unique names, such as user defined functions, objects/classes, variable names, included filenames, variable values, array names...I'm not sure what you think you could match up within the code to return useful results.

Even matching the constant things like PHP defined functions (eg `strlen()`), there are so many potential similar matches for specific parts of the code where it's always a constant name, yet the purpose of the code will be entirely different most times, and even then similar matches is unlikely to be directly useful.

The matching of constant names is pointless unless someone is just trying to learn about a function generically, and then tutorials/php.net etc have better more concise references.
I imagine this will be the case for a lot of languages/tags.

If you can come up with a way your proposal would work that counters this, then please edit your question.  In theory, your idea sounds good, I just don't see a practical use for it :)

Comment: Now I see that **SO** doesn't need such kind of feature because it is doing well at the moment. Thanks everybody for all comments!